# How do I browse through my account history?

Tags: support, questions, search, user-accounts

How do I browse through my account history on Stack Overflow? I have signed in with a Stack Exchange account. I want to revisit a recent question I visited, but I forgot the title.

Comment: There is no recorded history of questions you *visited* on Stack Overflow. Use your browser history functionality for that.