# What should I do when a duplicate question links to another duplicate question

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-suggestions

The question "[How do I browse through my account history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217110/351462)" was closed for being a duplicate.

[image]

The linked question "[Tracking the questions you've recently viewed or visited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30500/351462)" was ***also*** closed as a duplicate question.

[image]

Following this link leads us to the actual question we're looking for, "[Add a "recently viewed" tab in the user account page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67675/351462)".

[image]

How should these scenarios be handled? Is there a way to suggest updates to the referenced duplicate question?

---

**Edit:** This question is different from [Duplicates of duplicates should be remapped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199788/351462). I am asking what I should do as a user when duplicates of duplicates are found, while the linked question asks whether duplicate links should be remapped automatically.

Comment: Ironically, I do not think that is actually a duplicate. The suggested duplicate appears to outright suggest a change to implement "master duping", where I interpret this question to focus more on "why does this happen, and what should I do when I see it".

Comment: @Gnemlock You hit the nail on the head.

Comment: "it assumes that there are no answers of any value in any of the intermediate questions" https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142238/avoid-chaining-exact-duplicates

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed this a few times with other questions as well. I think it seems to be a case of people finding the duplicate topic but instead of going through each question to find the original their stopping at the first one they see.

***I've done this on the past too***, sometimes it can't be helped and you miss the notice message. I think you should just *make sure to find the original question as best you can* and flag it as a duplicate of that. If all else fails, let a moderator know.

It's not the end of the world though. Even though there isn't a direct link, you can still get to it by clicking through. As long as the question is marked as a duplicate appropriately then it'll be alright as far as I'm concerned. This being my opinion on the matter anyway.